# NHibernate QueryOver with Fetch resulting multiple sql queries and db hits

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fetch, queryover

I'm trying to select an entity and fetch a related list:

```
    Session.QueryOver<UserRole>()
           .Fetch(x => x.UsersInRole).Eager
           .List();
```

Which results in a lot of database hits.
The first one is something like:

> ```
>  SELECT ... FROM UserRoles
>  left outer join UsersInRoles on ...
> ```

And hundreds more seperate queries which looks something like:

> ```
>  SELECT ... FROM UsersInRoles
>  left outer join UserRoles on ...
>  WHERE UserRoles.UserId=?
> ```

The mapping is as following:

```
public class UserRoleMap : ClassMap<UserRole>
{
    public UserRoleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.RoleName);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.UsersInRole)
        .Inverse()
        .LazyLoad()
        .Table("UsersInRoles");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, that this behaviour is what we should expect. Let's have a scenario, in which we have in the system 2 users and 2 roles

```
User1 - Role1 // has only Role1
User2 - Role1 // now we see that Role2 has more then User1
User2 - Role2
```

Let's say, that the first query, will retrieve only *User1* and its many-to-many relation *Role1*. What we have in the `ISession` at the moment is only *User1*, so the set of Users for *Role1* is **incomplete** *(we cannot reuse objects loaded into ISession at the moment)*. But how should one know where we are? That all data loaded for `Role1` is or is not in the session?

New query, loading the data for `Role1` must be issued. And this way, we can at the end have dosens of these queries...

What I see as the best solution (I am using it in almost all scenarios) is the `batch-size` setting: [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.UsersInRole)
  ...
  .BatchSize(25)
```

Mark all your collection maps with `.BatchSize(25)` and do that even for the Class map as well. That will cause more then 1 SQL Script, but at the end **not** more then 1 + (2-4) dependent on the batch-size and page size.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Resulted in 1 + 12 queries - MUCH better then before, but isn't there's a way to make it less then 12? (increasing the batch size?) - what is the cost of batch size? I would geuss that if it was all good it would have been set by default.
Is the batch size the only solution? Isn't there's a possible join that will results in 2 queries? If I would of needed to write it my self with simple SQL I think 2 queries would have been enough. Thanks.

Comment: If there is any better solution than batch-size, maybe, I am not sure. The reason why this is not turned on by default, could be the fact, that this is breaking straightforward logic: The Proxy of uninitialize object is a driver. It directly goes for its data when needed. The batch-sizing moves some more effort on session to join these SELECTS. Anyway, Batch size is on all *our* collections and class mappings. And the performance is amazing even on large sets