# nHibernate - list of parents and child collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have this schema:

[image]

I have already done ManyToMany mapping between `Post` and `Tag`. What I'm trying to achieve is get the list of Posts and for each Post its child collection of Tags. So it can be displayed like this:

[image]

What I have done so far is this:

```
IList<Post> results = base._session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Post))
    .SetFetchMode("User", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Votes", FetchMode.Eager)
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("_dateCreated"))
    .ToList();
```

But for every `Post` it does 1 extra SQL to fetch `Votes`. 
Is there a way to fetch it in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in this case could/should be the batch fetching. Here: [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch) you can find more details.

You have to mark your collections and/or entities with an attribute `batch-szie="25"`.

xml:

```
<bag name="Tags" ... batch-size="25">
...
```

fluent:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags)
  ...
  .BatchSize(25)
```

That will still execute few SQL Select statements, not only one, but the flexibility you gain would be significant.

Here I've tried to explain why the batch fetching is the right way to go: [NHibernate QueryOver with Fetch resulting multiple sql queries and db hits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19284228/1679310)

At the end, we can use simple queries *(not explicit fetching)*, because `batch-size` will reduce the amount of SQL Statements issued to get all needed lazy loads...

Comment: For the list of 10 title posts displayed on the page it reduced 11 SQLs to just 2. Brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: Great if that helped ;) Enjoy NHiberante.. amazing tool