# Nhibernate query over with multiple fetch and multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

How can I get same result with NHibernate `QueryOver` when using entity framework `linq` like this.

```
var result = items
   .include("subEntity1")
   .include("subEntity2")
   .include("subEntity3")
   .where(...).skip(x).take(y);
```

Answer (score 3):

A syntax with `QueryOver` could look like this:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<MyEntity>()
    // force the collection inclusion
    .Fetch(x => x.Collection1).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.Collection2).Eager
    ...
    // force the relations inclusion
    .Fetch(x => x.SubEntity1).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.SubEntity2).Eager
    ...
    // paging
    .Skip(x)
    .Take(y);

var list = query
     .List<MyEntity>();
```

Sources:

- [15.5. Dynamic association fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-dynamicfetching)
- [16. QueryOver Queries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover)

Comment: I try this one but I'm getting duplicate entity in the result

Comment: Yes, that's the impact of the Fetch - collection. It always results in carthesian product. The appropriate way is in fact to do **NOT** Fetch. Change your mapping to a use batch-size, which will end in more then 1 query, but still very efficient. Please, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/19287008/1679310